# SQL search: contains with a single char (§) + numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I want search a single char + numbers (e.g. § 12345) with contains in a sql server (MS SQL server 2016).

I have created a fulltext catalog and custom stopwords.
The following where works fine:

```
where contains(Html, '12345')
```

But if I try search a paragraph (§), it doesn't work:

`where contains(Html, '§ AND 12345')` or `where contains(Html, '"§*" AND 12345')`

The paragraph is not a stopword.

Is there a posibility to solve this problem with contains and without using like?

Answer (score 1):

[AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a keyword used in boolean expressions and not inside a string.
You need something like this:

```
where contains(Html, '§') AND contains(Html, '12345')
```